# Is there a way to include Dagger 2 generated code in AAR?

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2, aar, maven-publish

I need to integrate an internal library with two apps. The problem is that those apps use different versions of Dagger 2 which are incompatible and I can't remove Dagger from the library fast. Is there a way to include Dagger generated classes in AAR?